# controller not call add action method - code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Controller does not call add action method in code igniter.

My controller is not calling add view or not calling add method, it shows a 404 error or it may be the issue of url or something like routes.

```
class Incomeexpense extends MX_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

  }


  function add()
  {
    meta['page_title'] = $this->lang->line("Incomeexpense");
    $data['page_title'] = $this->lang->line("Incomeexpense");
    $this->load->view('commons/header', $meta);
    $this->load->view('add',$data);
    $this->load->view('commons/footer');
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you configured your routes for that function maybe why not seeing page.

Comment: is there file called add in view folder?

Comment: Can you please add your full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MX_Controller which is HMVC

In Application folder Check If Like I have Just named module_folder as example you can rename it.

```
modules
modules > module_folder 
modules > module_folder > controllers 
modules > module_folder > controllers > Incomeexpense.php
modules > module_folder > views
modules > module_folder > views > add.php
modules > module_folder > views > commons > header.php
modules > module_folder > views > commons > footer.php
```

Route.php

```
$route['incomeexpense'] = "module_folder/incomeexpense/index";
$route['incomeexpense/add'] = "module_folder/incomeexpense/add";
```

Your url would be then

`http://localhost/project/incomeexpense/add`

**I am not sure if you have removed your index.php then would be**

`http://localhost/project/index.php/incomeexpense/add`

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Incomeexpense extends MX_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {

}

public function add() {
    $this->load->lang('some_file', 'english');

    $meta['page_title'] = $this->lang->line("Incomeexpense");
    $data['page_title'] = $this->lang->line("Incomeexpense");
    $this->load->view('commons/header', $meta);
    $this->load->view('add',$data);
    $this->load->view('commons/footer');
}
}
```

[How To Use HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

Comment: How you know he is using HMVC? if you need more clarification you can ask question by comment to the question.

Comment: Because he is extending controller MX_Controller